# Is the ANTLR3 C Target Thread Safe?

Tags: c, thread-safety, antlr3

Is the ANTLR3 C Target Thread Safe?

Answer (score 1):

You generally bind your own code to ANTLR trees, so that's entirely up to you to ensure.

Comment: So if i do something like this in my grammer:
@members{
  Type val;
}

val will be global and this won't be thread safe i guess.

But how is it with 
scope{
  Type val;
}

would this work?